# Why Illustrator CS5 Expand breaks my shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Ok, so I got a logo that's made of group of compound paths with appearance, I've already Expanded it once, so appearances (strokes only) are separate paths, and what I'm doing next it taking *all* the objects from the whole document and expanding them so there's no appearances or anything that wouldn't act 100% accurate while scaling.

Then, something unexpected happened. (The image is from a small portion of a poster, containing an obvious problem.) It seems as if the outer path of the O in PARTIO wouldn be open ended, but it's not. Both, the inner and the outer path of the O are two anchored paths. BTW, tried "outline path" as well as Expand, didn't make any difference. It just breaks.

### Why?

[image: Breaking things up with tools that shouldn't.]

After a little bit of experimenting, I noticed that by adding third anchor point I can prevent the breaking, so I guess this is just a bug, and can't be helped, but can't be sure. I'll provide a picture here with the problem in detail and the workaround:
[image: the workaround of the day]

I applied the third anchor to all of the 3 shapes, approximately to the same point, and it worked wonders. Only thing is, what if I had a blend of 1000 steps, would I go all the way? Hmm.. not unless it paid *really* well ;).

Comment: What happens if you run Simplify Path before expanding?

Answer (score 2):

That is a bug. Report it to Adobe [here](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform).

Comment: I'm not gonna participate in free program developement for something that costs more than spacetravelling. They can do their own gruntwork ;)

Comment: "This bug is a problem to me. If I report it, someone can fix it. But I will not report it, because I am having a tantrum and want others to suffer as I have suffered, so that they will know the pain I feel." Dramatic, but not very useful.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know space travel had gotten so cheap!

Comment: @jhocking - Yeah! I did that when I was 5 ... Just had to get a good big box and a marker. That technology has been around literally for years now!